# How do I solve a system of second order differential equations using Octave?

Tags: graph, octave, differential-equations

I am trying to solve two equations below for my project. I was unable to find any straightforward guide to solving the differential equations.

I am trying to plot a graph of h over time for the equations with a given initial h, miu, r, theta, g, L, and derivatives of h and theta wrt t. Is this possible? And if so, how?

[The two equations mentioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC2iP.png)

I tried to type the equations into Octave with the given conditions, but there seems to be an error that I am unable to identify.

Comment: Welcome! This is much like a translation request (suffers the same issues). [Programming language translation is generally too broad to be on-topic for Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296126/11107541). Please read the exceptions to learn what kind of "translation questions" you can ask here.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever is the *numerical* software you will use, Octave or another one (that does not *formal* calculation), the first step is to transform your system or N coupled Ordinary Differential Equations (ODEs) of order p into a system of p*N coupled ODEs of order **1**.

This is always done by setting intermediate derivatives as new variables.
For your system, then
[image]

will become

[image]

Then, with Octave, and as explained in `doc lsode` you define a function say `Xdot = dsys(X)`, that codes this system. `X` is the vector `[h, theta, H, J]`, and `Xdot` is the returned vector of their respective derivatives, as defined by the right hand expressions of the system of first order ODEs.

So, the 2 first elements of `Xdot` will be trivial, just `Xdot=[X(3) X(4) ...]`.

Of course,  `dsys()` must also use the parameters `M, g, m, µ, L`, and `r`. As far as i understand, they can't be passed as additional arguments to `dsys()`. So you must defined them before calling `lsode`.

For initial states, you must define the vector `X0=[h0, theta0, H0, J0]` of known initial values.

The vector of increasing times >= 0 to which you want to compute and get the values of X must then be defined. For instance, `t = 0:100`. 0 must be the first element of `t`.

Finally, call `Xt = lsode(@dsys, X0, t)`. After that you should get

- `Xt(:,1)` are the values of `h(t)`
- `Xt(:,2)` are the values of `theta(t)`
- `Xt(:,3)` are the values of `H(t)=(dh/dt)(t)`
- `Xt(:,4)` are the values of `J(t)=(dtheta/dt)(t)`